# Firebase Asking to initialize app even though it has already been initialized

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I created this test file to check for available firebase users and then move to the appropriate screen according to the response. Although I have initialized the app, it still show the error that no Firebase DEFAULT APP HAS BEEN CREATED. Call Firebase.initializeApp. Am i doing something wrong here? Also if there is any other way to check for the user being logged in or not then please tell. Keep in mind I need to fetch the data from firestore too before showing MainView().

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_easyloading/flutter_easyloading.dart';
import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';

import 'MainPages/LoginScreen.dart';
import 'MainPages/MainView.dart';
import 'Services/User.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(
    new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      builder: EasyLoading.init(),
      home: new MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future<Widget> loadFromFuture() async {

    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
      DocumentSnapshot doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
          .get();
      currentUser = MyUser.fromDocument(doc);
      return Future.value(new MainView());
    } else {
      return Future.value(new LoginScreen());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SplashScreen(
        navigateAfterFuture: loadFromFuture(),
        title: new Text(
          'Welcome In SplashScreen',
          style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
        image: new Image.network('https://i.imgur.com/TyCSG9A.png'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        styleTextUnderTheLoader: new TextStyle(),
        photoSize: 100.0,
        onClick: () => print("Flutter Egypt"),
        loaderColor: Colors.red);
  }
}
```

Comment: Make the main function async and await Firebase.initializeApp();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to await for firebase to be initialized

Please refer below code

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```